# Entity Framework generate wrong query in many to many relationship database-first

Tags: entity-framework-core

i have relation ship across 6 tables:
associative model:

```
public class Product
{

   

   public int? GameId { get; set; }
 
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; } 

    public int? PlatformId { get; set; }

    public virtual Platform Platform { get; set; } 

    public int? ManufactureId { get; set; }
 
    public virtual Manufacture Manufacture { get; set; }

    public int? LocalizationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Localization Localization { get; set; }

    public int? GenreId { get; set; }
  
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; } 

    public int? RegionrestrictId { get; set; }
  
    public virtual Country RegionRestrict { get; set; } 





}
```

main related table:

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

 
    public string Titleofgame { get; set; }


    public string Description { get; set; }


    public DateTime DateRelese { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Manufacture> Manufactures { get; set; } = new List<Manufacture>();


    public  List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();

    public int? Idseriesofgame { get; set; }

    public Serie Series { get; set; }


    public int? Idpublication { get; set; }

    public Publication Publication { get; set; }



    public virtual List<Platform> Platforms { get; set; } = new List<Platform>();





 
    public virtual List<Localization> Localizations { get; set; } = new List<Localization>();


   
    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; } = new List<Genre>();

   
    public virtual List<Country> RegionRestricts { get; set; } = new List<Country>();


 
  
}
```

and one of the tables which related with "Game"(rest tables are the same)

```
 public class Localization
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Язык")]

    public string Titleoflocalization { get; set; }
  
    public virtual List<Game> Games { get; set; } = new List<Game>();
 
    public  List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

Fluent Api configuration:

```
     modelBuilder
      .Entity<Game>()
      .HasMany(c => c.Localizations)
      .WithMany(s => s.Games)
      .UsingEntity<Product>(
         j =>
          j.HasOne(pt => pt.Localization)
          .WithMany(t => t.Products)
          .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.LocalizationId),
      j =>
          j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
          .WithMany(p => p.Products)
          .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


      j =>
      {

          j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId, t.LocalizationId });
          j.ToTable("Products");
      }
  );

        modelBuilder
          .Entity<Game>()
          .HasMany(c => c.Platforms)
          .WithMany(s => s.Games)
          .UsingEntity<Product>(
             j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Platform)
              .WithMany(t => t.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PlatformId),
          j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
              .WithMany(p => p.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


          j =>
          {

              j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId,   t.LocalizationId });
              j.ToTable("Products");
          }
      );


        modelBuilder
          .Entity<Game>()
          .HasMany(c => c.Genres)
          .WithMany(s => s.Games)
          .UsingEntity<Product>(
             j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Genre)
              .WithMany(t => t.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GenreId),
          j =>
              j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
              .WithMany(p => p.Products)
              .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


          j =>
          {

              j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId,  t.LocalizationId });
              j.ToTable("Products");
          }
      );


        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Game>()
            .HasMany(c => c.RegionRestricts)
            .WithMany(s => s.Games)
            .UsingEntity<Product>(
               j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.RegionRestrict)
                .WithMany(t => t.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RegionrestrictId),
            j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
                .WithMany(p => p.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId),


            j =>
            {

                j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId , t.LocalizationId});
                j.ToTable("Products");
            }
        );



        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
   .HasOne(a => a.Series)
   .WithMany(a => a.Games)
   .HasForeignKey(c => c.Idseriesofgame);

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<Game>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Manufactures)
            .WithMany(s => s.Games)
            .UsingEntity<Product>(
               j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.Manufacture)
                .WithMany(t => t.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ManufactureId),
            j =>
                j.HasOne(pt => pt.Game)
                .WithMany(p => p.Products)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.GameId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade),



            j =>
            {

                j.HasKey(t => new { t.GameId, t.ManufactureId, t.GenreId, t.PlatformId, t.RegionrestrictId });
                j.ToTable("Products");
            }
        );




        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasMany(d => d.Products).WithOne(d => d.Game).HasForeignKey(d => d.GameId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

       
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Game)
            .WithMany(b => b.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.GameId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.RegionRestrict)
            .WithMany(b => b.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.RegionrestrictId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Genre)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.GenreId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Localization)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.LocalizationId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Manufacture)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ManufactureId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasOne(bc => bc.Platform)
      .WithMany(b => b.Products)
      .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PlatformId);
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
      .HasKey(bc =>  bc.GameId );
            modelBuilder.Entity<Game>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Genre>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Localization>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Manufacture>().HasKey(p => p.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Platform>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
```

and when i'm trying to remove for example genre by condition:

```
      Product product = new Product() { GameId = 1, GenreId =1};
          
            _context.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Deleted;


            var game = publication.Game;
            
        
            game.Products.Remove(product);


            _context.SaveChanges();;
```

(product with genreid==1 and gameid==1 only one):

[image]

i'm getting exception:
[image]
and i notice a query, which entity framework genereted:

```
 bug: 20.08.2021 00:25:51.250 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@p0='1'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DELETE FROM `Products`
      WHERE `gameid` = @p0;
      SELECT ROW_COUNT();
info: 20.08.2021 00:25:51.253 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted[20101] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command) 
      Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p0='1'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      DELETE FROM `Products`
      WHERE `gameid` = @p0;
      SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

By the way, when i try to add- all is good.I dont know what i'm doing wrong. Please, help me.

Comment: Product has key `GameId`, it's suspicious.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Product has no primary key, i pointed it out in MySql, but i'm not shure, that my configuration is correct